# Getting mysql data where all rows have same column value

Tags: mysql

I want to get all rows with same part value, like

```
1. lesson 1 part=1
2. lesson 1.1 part=1
3. lesson 2 part=2
```

I want to get lesson 1 and 1.1 because their part is equal

```
wl - What lesson from math
lessons - first table
ls - second table
lid - lesson id from lessons table
Just to get non seen lessons.

"SELECT * FROM lessons 
WHERE wl='$math' 
AND id IN(SELECT lid FROM ls WHERE fid='$user' AND seen='0') 
GROUP BY part LIMIT 2";
```

Comment: so, you need to get those lessons which have more than one same `part` value?

Comment: Don't use group by like this if you can avoid it.  Instead of a list of "stuff", can you give us table descriptions with data output?

Comment: I need 2 same because they can have only 2 same but yeah more than one.

Comment: It doesn't matter I just did by finding the first one, because they are connected and when I update ls - second table it will put seen as 1 for both. I just wanted it as secure way if one is seen 0 and second is seen 1 which can't be possible. But in case it happens I wanted to be sure if there are 2 rows with same part and where seen is 0.

Comment: the last question: you need to extract all fields from the grouped lessons or just their
 ids?

Comment: just ids and parts, because I need to check rows and part and seen values are the same. output is just to say $part = $row['part']; and then somewhere on thee page from math lessons this  is part 1 then i have controls to by that part 1 go next to part 2 etc. if those parts are seen when user again opens the page it will search for unseen parts.

Answer (score 0):

As this is just for you to look up the records, it probably suffices to get a list of IDs for each part, for which you can use `GROUP_CONCAT`:

```
SELECT part, GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids
FROM lessons 
WHERE wl='$math' 
AND id IN(SELECT lid FROM ls WHERE fid='$user' AND seen='0') 
GROUP BY part
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

If you wanted a row per part and ID that would be more difficult. Such problems are usually solved with analytic functions, but MySQL doesn't feature them yet. This makes it necessary to write part of the query twice.

This is how to get the unseen lessons for the user:

```
SELECT *
FROM lessons 
WHERE wl='$math' 
AND id IN(SELECT lid FROM ls WHERE fid='$user' AND seen='0');
```

And this is how you get the parts that appear more than once in the results:

```
SELECT part 
FROM lessons 
WHERE wl='$math' 
AND id IN(SELECT lid FROM ls WHERE fid='$user' AND seen='0') 
GROUP BY part
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

The two combined:

```
SELECT *
FROM lessons 
WHERE wl='$math' 
AND id IN(SELECT lid FROM ls WHERE fid='$user' AND seen='0')
AND part IN
(
  SELECT part 
  FROM lessons 
  WHERE wl='$math' 
  AND id IN(SELECT lid FROM ls WHERE fid='$user' AND seen='0') 
  GROUP BY part
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your condition *"I need 2 same because they can have only 2 same"* - use the following query:

```
SELECT 
    id, part
FROM 
    lessons 
WHERE 
    id REGEXP
    (SELECT 
        group_concat(id separator '|')
    FROM 
        lessons 
    WHERE 
        wl='$math' 
        AND id IN (SELECT lid FROM ls WHERE fid='$user' AND seen='0') 
    GROUP BY part
    HAVING count(part) = 2)
```